# Plot() function in R disorganized categorical x-values from .csv

Tags: r, csv, plot

I am trying to create a barplot of household income, but the x-values are in the wrong order.

Here's the categories household income I got from my work's API: "0-15k", "15k-25k", "25k-35k", "35k-50k", "50k-75k", "75k-100k", "100k-125k", "125k-150k", "150k-175k", "175k-200k", "200k-250k", "250k+". I took out the names of the email for privacy and used the first 25 rows only.

My script:

```
#Load Data
Store2 <- read.csv("/Users/Documents/Work/Data/Client2.csv", 
                   na.strings = "", head = TRUE)
#First 25 rows
                               Email    Age Gender    HouseholdIncome     MaritalStatus
1                            @aol.com  <NA>   Male            <NA>          <NA>
2                          @yahoo.com 45-54 Female            <NA>          <NA>
3                      @stratatec.com  <NA>   <NA>            <NA>          <NA>
4                          @gmail.com  <NA>   <NA>            <NA>          <NA>
5                         5@yahoo.com 45-54 Female        75k-100k       Married
6                            @aol.com 25-34   Male        75k-100k       Married
7                          @yahoo.com 35-44 Female       125k-150k       Married
8                     d@sbcglobal.net 55-64   Male        75k-100k       Married
9                          @yahoo.com   65+ Female         25k-35k       Married
10                            @me.com  <NA> Female            <NA>          <NA>
11                     @sunupcorp.com  <NA> Female            <NA>          <NA>
12                         @yahoo.com 45-54   Male        75k-100k       Married
13                           @att.net  <NA>   <NA>            <NA>          <NA>
14                       @verizon.net  <NA>   Male            <NA>          <NA>
15                         @yahoo.com 45-54   Male         50k-75k          <NA>
16                         @gmail.com 45-54   Male         50k-75k          <NA>
17                    @roadrunner.com 45-54 Female         15k-25k        Single
18                           @aol.com 35-44   Male         50k-75k        Single
19                         @yahoo.com 45-54   Male       125k-150k        Single
20                           @aol.com  <NA>   <NA>            <NA>          <NA>
21                         @gmail.com 25-34   Male            <NA>          <NA>
22                         @yahoo.com 25-34   Male         50k-75k        Single
23                         @gmail.com 55-64   Male       150k-175k       Married
24                   @trellnjoyce.com  <NA> Female         35k-50k       Married
25                           @aol.com   65+   Male         50k-75k       Married
```

**EDIT:** I made the changes to the plot, but the X-axis label is in the way.

```
#Plot of Household Income 
res <- ordered(Store2$HouseholdIncome, levels=c("0-15k", "15k-25k", "25k-35k", 
                                                "35k-50k", "50k-75k", "75k-100k", 
                                                "100k-125k", "125k-150k", "150k-175k", 
                                                "175k-200k", "200k-250k", "250k+"))
#Set dimensions
par(mar=c(8,4,4,3))
#Create plot
plot(res, main = "Distribution of Household Income", xlab = "", 
     ylab = "Density", las=2, ylim = c(0,2000))
mtext(text="HouseholdIncome", side=1, line=6)
```

[image]

Comment: One way to solve is to organize factor level. `A = unique(data$HouseholdIncome)`   `data$HouseholdIncome = factor(data$HouseholdIncome, A[blah blah...]`    Blahblah should be the order you want to plot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you properly order the levels of the HouseholdIncome factor, e.g., like so:

```
    res <- ordered(Store2$HouseholdIncome, levels=c("0-15k", "15k-25k", "25k-35k", "35k-50k", "50k-75k", "75k-100k", "100k-125k", "125k-150k", "150k-175k", "175k-200k", "200k-250k", "250k+"))

par(mar=c(10,3,3,3))    
plot(res, main = "Distribution of Household Income", 
         xlab = "", ylab = "Density", las=2)
    mtext(text="HouseholdIncome", side=1, line=3)
```

Comment: It doesn't *have* to be an `ordered` factor but in this case that certainly makes sense.

Comment: You're right. Just seems a fairly easy solution in this case.

Comment: @meuleman I made the edit, but ran into another problem. The x-axis labels are in the way of the x-axis description.

Comment: @ScottDavis you can set `xlab=""` in the `plot()` command, and then manually add the label after using `mtext()`, using a line offset. I've edited my original answer to include this.

Comment: @meuleman I used the edited script, but the result is the same. I tried changing to line five, but "HouseholdIncome" goes too far down and off the plot (not visible).

Comment: Yes, you have to change your margins accordingly, e.g., using `par(mar=c(10,3,3,3))` before you use `plot()`.

Comment: @meuleman It seemed like everything shrunk after using the par() function. I changed the 10 to 9,8,7,6 and 5, but the same problem occured.

Comment: @ScottDavis not sure what to say. the `par(mar())` command makes the margins larger, so the figure shrinks indeed. Play around with the sizes of the margins, as well as with the `line=3` parameters of `mtext()` and you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: @meuleman I played around with the par() and mtext() function and got a good graph. Thanks again!